# Why is htmlpurifier removing allowed IMG tag?

Tags: html, htmlpurifier

I have put this simple malformed HTML into [htmlpurifier demo page (link with my test html)](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=1&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=1&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.Allowed%5D=p%0D%0Aimg&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=text1%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%3C/p%3E%0D%0A%3Cimg%20src=%22/x.gif%22%20alt=%22alt%22%3E%3Cdiv%3Etext2%3C/div%3E&submit=Submit):

```
text1
<p></p>
<img src="/x.gif" alt="alt">
<div>text2</div>
```

I have also specified whitelist of "p" and "img" tags.

However, the resulting output is this:

```
<p>text1
</p><p>
text2</p>
```

Why is htmlpurifier removing IMG tag, even though it is whitelisted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell it to allow the `src` and `alt` attributes explicitly.  Specify in the HTML allowed box (`$HTML.Allowed`):

```
p
img[alt|src]
```

Comment: The fix helps. Apparently HTML Purifier has some oddities with regard to the `img` element: it complains about a missing `alt` attribute (probably due to the way it parses HTML), despite additionally saying that it is disallowed. Moreover, with just `img` in the white list, it removes the entire `img` element, not just the attributes (whereas if you use e.g. `<p align=left>` and whitelisted just `p` and not `p[align], it removes the attribute but not the element).

Comment: Did you see the itemized list of actions in the pink box? It tells you everything it's doing, so when I got inconsistent messages ("alt" required and "alt" remvoed) I decided there must be some conflicting rules at work.  Since you delete ALL th attributes and thre was no content, it removed the tab as well, probably because it understands that what's left will render nothing.